# Assembly redirect not working for SSIS script task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, script-task, assembly-binding-redirect, ssis-2016

We've a requirement where some SSIS packages need to run on multiple SQL Server versions (2014 and 2016), without us having to maintain 2 versions of the code base.

I've built a wrapper C# console app which has assembly redirects (listed below) in the config and it later calls the Package.Execute method to execute the DTSX file.

I'm getting the below error which tells me that the latest version of the Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask assembly found on the machine is getting loaded. The machine currently has v12, 13 and 14 assemblies at the moment. And I need to use v13 since I'm targeting SQL Server 2016.

Any ideas why it would do that and how I can 'resolve' it correctly?

***Error***:

> CS1705 - Assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' uses 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

***Redirects in console app config***:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>   </runtime>
```

Comment: you have to check if there are main differences between different ManagedDTS assemblies objects and classes. If these differences are found i think that you must agree with the answer provided. Else you can go with the question you asked

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a package designed for specific SQL Server version to run using a different version DLL's. Also when a package is upgraded to a higher version. you cannot execute it in a lower version.

Assembly binding redirect is not made for a similar case. Because the classes and objects differs between versions.

Comment: Well, I know that a package once upgraded cannot be degraded back. We are thinking on the lines where upgradation can happen dynamically without having to maintain 2 versions of the same package.

Comment: @Ash i think that what your are working on is very interesting, i will be waiting for the results, and hope that you will find a good solution. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You have to change at least the `newversion` property of `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS` to `14.0.0.0` for SQL server 2016 (and potentially to the other `newversion` attributes as well)

`<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>`